# SQL delete query is taking too long , 20k records to be deleted from half million records

Tags: mysql, heidisql

In my database i have around **500,000 records**. I have applied a query to delete around **20,000 records**.

Its been 45 minutes that Heidi SQL is showing that the command is being executed.

Here is my command -

`DELETE FROM DIRECTINOUT_MSQL WHERE MACHINENO LIKE '%TEXAOUT%' AND DATASENT = 1 AND UPDATETIME = NULL AND DATE <= '2017/4/30';`

Please advise, how to avoid these kind of situations in future and what should i do now ? Shall i disintegrate this query with some condition and execute smaller query ?

I have exported my database **backup file**, its around **47mb**

Kindly advise.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns in the where clause?

Comment: Could you share your table schema, are you using innodb or myisam?

Comment: We have simply installed mysql.exe and we apply commands using HeidiSQL, i dont know what is myLsm or InnoDB

Comment: Can you eliminate the % sign at the beginning of `MACHINENO LIKE '%TEXAOUT%'` as this will mean it has to work with every record.

Answer (score 1):

Try index method. It will improve your query performance

Database index, or just index, helps speed up the retrieval of data from tables. When you query data from a table, first MySQL checks if the indexes exist, then MySQL uses the indexes to select exact physical corresponding rows of the table instead of scanning the whole table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Can you expand your answer, what is index method? Could you provide a query using this method?

Comment: We killed the session, We added index and then query executed in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What is the engine you are using myIsm or InnoDB?
I guess you are using mysql database,
What is the isolation level set on the database?
how much time does a select of that data takes? please see that there is in some cases limits that make you thin that query finished within few seconds but you got only part of the results.

Comment: We have simply installed mysql.exe and we apply commands using HeidiSQL, i dont know what is myLsm or InnoDB

Comment: OK, is someone/ any application running selects from this table on this period of time?

Comment: Yes a select command was running in same schema but on other table.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. I solved it using a loop.
You have to first write a query with fast select to check if you have records to delete:

```
SELECT COUNT(SOME_ID) FROM DIRECTINOUT_MSQL WHERE MACHINENO LIKE '%TEXAOUT%' AND DATASENT = 1 AND UPDATETIME = NULL AND DATE <= '2017/4/30' LIMIT 1
```

While you have a count of 1 for this query then do this:

```
DELETE FROM DIRECTINOUT_MSQL WHERE MACHINENO LIKE '%TEXAOUT%' AND DATASENT = 1 AND UPDATETIME = NULL AND DATE <= '2017/4/30' LIMIT 1000
```

I just chose 1000 randomly, but you have to see what is the fastest limit for the DELETE statement for you server configuration.